# How to loop through files and exclude specific file types

Tags: powershell

So I'm new to powershell development and writing a script that works with zip files. I can zip everything in a folder just fine, but what I'm really trying to do is loop through the directory, if there is a file with a certain extension, so let's say .txt, then it won't zip that file. I know about 3rd party extensions but I don't want to rely on those since I plan on letting other people use these scripts.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to "loop through" anything; use the `-exclude` parameter for `get-childitem` to exclude any file with the `.txt` extension. Then pass the resulting collection of files to whatever is doing your zipping.

```
get-childitem -Exclude *.txt
```

Comment: So when I use this method and try to pass it through createFromDirectory (by first putting it into a variable) I get errored out saying the path is too long. This makes sense, as it's trying to pass the whole directory as a path. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Is `createFromDirectory` capable of handling data via the pipeline? Or an array of objects? You're going to have to show a lot more code if you want help on that part, but it should probably be a separate question - you asked how to exclude a file extension, that's the answer I provided.